# Is asking questions related to the statements in (religious) scriptures allowed?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

There are many facts in scriptures across the world. They are mentioned very earlier compared to their formal verification with modern science.

Assume that a fact has been proved by the *modern* science and the same fact was mentioned long ago in a religious book.

So there is an early mention of the fact proved by the modern science. So, the fact may be scientific for those generations whose proof was not presented in the book.

Are questions related to such facts allowed to ask in our main site? or the questions related to the modern science are only allowed?

Comment: Would you mind giving an example?

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11826/what-is-the-earliest-known-mention-of-time-dilation @HDE226868

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11267/mention-of-the-fact-sun-never-rises-or-sets @HDE226868